# How do I display an ActionMailer::MessageDeliveryobject in an html page?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, email, actionmailer

I have a rails app in which I am using Action Mailer to generate and send emails. I am planning to store important emails (not the welcome ones) in a database, so that it can be viewed as an HTML page later. Given that I have the 'mail' object as below, of class type MessageDelivery, is there a way by which I can display it's contents in an HTML page? The HTML page should display the to, from, subject,  the content and any embedded images.

```
mail = Notifier.welcome(User.first)  # an ActionMailer::MessageDelivery object
# how can i display this 'mail' object in html?
mail.deliver_now   # sends the email
```

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey you can display ActionMailer object in HTML. with

```
mail.html_part
```

You can also get plain text part with

```
mail.text_part
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: How do I display mail.html_part in a haml view?

Comment: If the mail body has 3 mimeparts, 1 part the content, and the 2nd and 3rd parts are image attachments, then, any idea how to link the images to references to those images in the content?